# R function to add a row runs line-by-line but not in a function

Tags: r, function

I'm just genuinely confused here.
So here is some code that works fine:

```
 insertion3=county$rpc85_weighted.mean[1]-county$rpc85_weighted.mean
  county$changed<-insertion3
```

I get the column with the values I want. But for some reason, when I make it into a function like this:

```
differences=function(county) {
  insertion3=county$rpc85_weighted.mean[1]-county$rpc85_weighted.mean
  county$changed<-insertion3
  return(county)
}
```

It stops at the <-insertion3 line and gives me the error that

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, changed, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 94
```

What's so different about it being a function

Comment: insertion3 is a number or a vector? If yes, in this assigment, county$changed<-insertion3, LHS is a vector, RHS is a number. May be you can replace insertion3 by rep(insertion3 , dim(county)[1])

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)